# Get "zero" for a count at dates without records

Tags: sql, sql-server

So I'm counting activity records from users in my system. I get the activity counter for each day in a certain month and year, just like the query that follows

```
SELECT CONVERT(date, VIS_DATETIME) AS DATETIME, COUNT(*) AS ACTIVITY
FROM ACTIVITY
WHERE DATEPART(year, VIS_DATETIME) = 2016 AND
      DATEPART(month, VIS_DATETIME) = 3
GROUP BY CONVERT(date, VIS_DATETIME)
ORDER BY CONVERT(date, VIS_DATETIME)
```

The question is, if, let's say, March 28th doesn't have any activity, it won't be even listed. But, for my charts API, I need to get that listed and with a `0` for the counter.

Obviously, accepting suggestions!

Comment: Discussed many times. You should have some calendar table. Then you take calendar table and do left join on ACTIVITY, grouping by ID of calendar table.

Comment: Was looking for something more innovative, but thanks!

Comment: A calendar table or a tally table is the best way to handle this. Not sure what else you would do. There has to be a row for sql server to return one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a table that contains all dates. Then do a left join with the Activity table. Group on the date, and do a `COUNT` on Activity.id. The left join ensures that all dates from the date table are included in the result set, even if they are not matched in the join clause.

Comment: Not saying that it's wrong but creating meaningless structures are a bad practice. Works for the application but ruins the DB schema. Like I said in the comment above, I was looking for a more innovative solution that I could do only with a query.

Comment: It is NOT a meaningless structure. This is an excellent place to use a tally table.

Comment: All dates table is very useful and not a meaningless structure at all. Why to create more innovative solution if this is the good and proven solution? :)

Comment: Ended up using tally table. Works good but still hurts my DBA-ish pride. hahaha

Answer (score 4):

```
Declare @DayOfMonth TinyInt Set @DayOfMonth = 1
Declare @Month TinyInt Set @Month = 1
Declare @Year Integer Set @Year = 2016
Declare @startDate datetime 
Declare @endDate datetime 
-- ------------------------------------
Select  @startDate = DateAdd(day, @DayOfMonth - 1, 
          DateAdd(month, @Month - 1, 
              DateAdd(Year, @Year-1900, 0)))

select @endDate  = dateadd(month,1,@startDate)

;with dateRange as
(
  select dt = dateadd(dd, 0, @startDate)
  where dateadd(dd, 0, @startDate) < @endDate
  union all
  select dateadd(dd, 1, dt)
  from dateRange
  where dateadd(dd, 1, dt) < @endDate
)
select *
from dateRange
```

The above query gives all the dates in the month,you can left join it with your aggregated query to get the entries with zero count.

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm, if you want innovative.  Here are two steps:

- Add a flag to the table about whether the activity is valid
- Add a job to SQL Server agent

How do these work?

```
alter table activity add column ActivityIsValid smallint default 1;
```

That way, new rows go in as a valid activity, not invalid.

Then schedule a SQL Server agent job to run the following code once per day:

```
insert into activity(vis_datetime, ActivityIsValid)
    values(cast(getdate() as date), 0);
```

Then you can run your query as:

```
SELECT CONVERT(date, VIS_DATETIME) AS DATETIME, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN ActivityIsValid = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS ACTIVITY
FROM ACTIVITY
WHERE VIS_DATETIME >= '2016-03-01' AND
      VIS_DATETIME < '2016-04-01        
GROUP BY CONVERT(date, VIS_DATETIME)
ORDER BY CONVERT(date, VIS_DATETIME);
```

Of course, this only works moving forward.  You can manually insert the extra rows in the historical data.

Also note the change to the `WHERE` clause.  By doing direct date comparisons, the SQL engine can make use of an index.

Comment: Can you explain about case statement inside sum i.e.,SUM(CASE WHEN ActivityIsValid = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END). What is the result of sum when 1 and 0?

Comment: That counts the number of rows where `ActivityIsValid` takes on the value of `1`.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to [Arun's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36263555/9972235) this will create a temp Table you can join on and save you creating a permanent table in database.

```
DECLARE @@startDate DATETIME = '2016-03-01';
DECLARE @@endDate DATETIME = '2016-03-31';

DECLARE @@tempCalendar TABLE (
    [Id] INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Year] INT NOT NULL,
    [Month] INT NOT NULL,
    [Day] INT NOT NULL
);

DECLARE @@dateCount DATETIME = @@startDate;

WHILE (@@dateCount <= @@endDate)
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO @@tempCalendar 
        VALUES (
            DATEPART(YEAR, @@dateCount)
            , DATEPART(MONTH, @@dateCount)
            , DATEPART(DAY, @@dateCount)
        );

        SET @@dateCount = DATEADD(DAY, 1, @@dateCount);
    END


SELECT c.[Year]
    , c.[Month]
    , c.[Day]
    , COUNT(a.Id) AS ACTIVITY

FROM @@tempCalendar c
    LEFT OUTER JOIN ACTIVITY a ON c.[Year] = DATEPART(YEAR, a.VIS_DATETIME)
                                AND c.[Month] = DATEPART(MONTH, a.VIS_DATETIME)
                                AND c.[Day] = DATEPART(DAY, a.VIS_DATETIME)

WHERE DATEPART(YEAR, a.VIS_DATETIME) = DATEPART(YEAR, @@startDate) 
    AND DATEPART(MONTH, a.VIS_DATETIME) = DATEPART(MONTH, @@startDate) 

GROUP BY c.[Year], c.[Month], c.[Day]
ORDER BY c.[Year], c.[Month], c.[Day];
```