# how can i find the count of rows for the particular month with all the days taken into account

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a student_registration table with columns like,

```
id name reg_date
1  John 2018-03-05
2  Ramu 2018-03-07
3  Merl 2018-03-07
4  Petr 2018-03-31
```

I want a count of students who registered daily for the particular month March

```
date        count

2018-03-01  0
2018-03-02  0
2018-03-03  0
2018-03-04  0
2018-03-05  1
2018-03-06  0
2018-03-07  2
------
------
2018-03-31  0
```

How can i achieve the above,

I tried this, but this query gives the record only for the count exists

```
SELECT Date(s.date_reg) AS month_date, 
       Count(s.id)                AS count_stud 
FROM   student_registration s
```

I dont have any other dates table that contains all the dates

Comment: To do this, you need to join with a master list of dates. Either generated table or a table that you can prepopulate with all the dates you need. Then you can join it with your data and you'll get 0's for the dates that have no data.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get "zero" for a count at dates without records](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36262810/get-zero-for-a-count-at-dates-without-records)

Comment: If you don't have a master list, you can dynamically create one in a query.

Answer (score 0):

You can generate dates by using the query below:

```
SELECT '2018-03-01' + INTERVAL t.n - 1 day day 
FROM   (SELECT a.n + b.n * 10 + 1 n 
        FROM   (SELECT 0 AS N 
                UNION ALL 
                SELECT 1 UNION ALL 
                SELECT 2 UNION ALL 
                SELECT 3 UNION ALL 
                SELECT 4 UNION ALL 
                SELECT 5 UNION ALL 
                SELECT 6 UNION ALL 
                SELECT 7 UNION ALL 
                SELECT 8 UNION ALL 
                SELECT 9) a, 
               (SELECT 0 AS N 
                UNION ALL 
                SELECT 1 UNION ALL 
                SELECT 2 UNION ALL 
                SELECT 3 UNION ALL 
                SELECT 4 UNION ALL 
                SELECT 5 UNION ALL 
                SELECT 6 UNION ALL 
                SELECT 7 UNION ALL 
                SELECT 8 UNION ALL 
                SELECT 9) b 
        ORDER  BY n) t
WHERE  t.n <= Datediff(Last_day('2018-03-01'), '2018-03-01')+ 1
```

You can change the numbers based on needs. To use this in your solution, you can join with this table.

```
SELECT Date(dts.day) AS month_date, 
   Count(s.id)   AS count_stud 
FROM   (SELECT '2018-03-01' + INTERVAL t.n - 1 day day 
    FROM   (SELECT a.n + b.n * 10 + 1 n 
            FROM   (SELECT 0 AS N 
                UNION ALL 
                SELECT 1 UNION ALL 
                SELECT 2 UNION ALL 
                SELECT 3 UNION ALL 
                SELECT 4 UNION ALL 
                SELECT 5 UNION ALL 
                SELECT 6 UNION ALL 
                SELECT 7 UNION ALL 
                SELECT 8 UNION ALL 
                SELECT 9) a, 
               (SELECT 0 AS N 
                UNION ALL 
                SELECT 1 UNION ALL 
                SELECT 2 UNION ALL 
                SELECT 3 UNION ALL 
                SELECT 4 UNION ALL 
                SELECT 5 UNION ALL 
                SELECT 6 UNION ALL 
                SELECT 7 UNION ALL 
                SELECT 8 UNION ALL 
                SELECT 9) b 
            ORDER  BY n) t 
    WHERE  t.n <= Datediff(Last_day('2018-03-01'), '2018-03-01') 
                  + 1) dts 
   LEFT OUTER JOIN student_registration s 
                ON Date(s.date_reg) = Date(dts.day)
```

There are different ways of doing this. This is one of the simpler ones that you can use without creating a new table. You can change the date range to get whatever timeline you need.